# CollectionViewCell not showing TextView

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom collection view cell:

```
class chatMessageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
let textView : UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.text = "SAMPLE TEXT"
    tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    return tv
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.addSubview(textView)

    textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

It is also registered:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "Chat"

    collectionView?.delegate = self
    collectionView?.dataSource = self

    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.register(chatMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)

}
```

and created with:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! chatMessageCell

let message = messages[indexPath.item]
cell.textView.text = message.text

return cell
}
```

However, there only appears a number of red cells on the screen, but they do not contain any text oder textView. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Override `awakeFromNib` method. Write code from `init` method to it.

Comment: That doesn't help. I mean - the red background color is set, so the method seems to work and to get called. But why don't I see any textView on the cells?

Comment: Hi, Did it work?

Answer (score 2):

You should add all subviews to UICollectionView's contentView, not into UICollectionView instance itself. So instead of this:

```
self.addSubview(textView)
```

Try this:

```
self.contentView.addSubview(textView)
```